# what does rake db:migrate do outside of looking at migration files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I'm trying to debug a problem I am having with migrating my db.

I had my application running without issue, and pushed it to heroku, and ran `rake db:migrate` and got the error

```
PG::Error: ERROR: relation "places" does not exist
LINE 4: WHERE a.attrelid = '"places"'::regclass
^
: SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
WHERE a.attrelid = '"places"'::regclass
AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum
```

I found it very strange that the migrations were fine locally, but not when migrating on the server. I found a few other people had had similar problems, but never found that anybody had a solution. No answers I found on StackOverflow had been accepted. After a few hours of trying different things, I thought I'd try to create a new heroku app from scratch and push my app to it (that worked for somebody else), basically starting fresh.

When I did that, I got the same error, but now on the `wineries`.

Weird, on the recommendation of Heroku, I tried creating a new db locally, and running my migrations.

Now locally, I get the same error, but on the table `admin_users`.

I'm pretty sure there is nothing wrong with the actual migration files, as each time I run the migration, I get a different table and therefore in some ways a different migration which is being affected.

I've tried removing a few gems, but still et the same error.

Does rake:db look outside any files other than the migration files? Could this be a relationship issue?

Any other suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you accessing/using any models in your migrations to do any data updates?  Are you using any models in anything in config/initializers?  rake db:migrate loads the rails environment so if you try and access a model that doesn't exist yet it will spit this error out...

Comment: Thanks Philip, I didn't have anything in my initializers but your routes are loaded in the environment as well (it appears) and it turns out that active_admin adds two lines to the routes `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config` which was causing the problem.